# in akka-http, how to match a path segment with an optional end slash?

Tags: akka-http

this path directive of akka http matches `/hello`

```
lazy val userRoutes: Route = cors() {
  path(Segment) { p => ... }
```

how can I match both `/hello` and `/hello/` (optional end slash)?

After reading the doc https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/index.html#pathdirectives
I've tried as follows, but it does not compile:

```
lazy val userRoutes: Route = cors() {
  rawPathPrefix(Slash ~ Segment ~ pathEndOrSingleSlash) { p => ... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akka-Http provides path directives using which you can solve the following.

```
val route =
  pathPrefix("hello") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      complete("/hello")
    }
  }
```

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/pathEndOrSingleSlash.html

Comment: I meant to match /hello, /hello/, /world, world/, any another other word (without any other slash in between). I guess that replacing "hello" by Segment in your post is the solution. Thanks!